# Handling JSON data safely in JS and HTML context

Tags: javascript, json, security, xss

I've read a lot about sanitizing and escaping of untrusted data, e.g. starting with this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md). But I didnt get the full picture yet. I am struggeling to understand, what principles I have to follow in order to parse JSON data safely.

Let's be more precise by means of an example. I retreive an Object in JSON format via an Ajax call from my server. The object shoudnt contain any malicious code, but.... you never now. So I parse the JSON data using JSON.parse in JS. The sesult is a multilevel JS object. I use the object in various way, e.g. creating table code via JS and writing it in the DOM.

Is this approach safe. Or do I have to somehow escape the invidual items of the object individually? Appreciate your help. Happy to concrete my example if necessary.

Comment: JSON on its own is not malicious.  It's when you take parts of the parsed object and use it that any stored code could run.

Comment: So ideally, any values from an object that originates from JSON, that you want to consider could be unsafe, if you were going to insert them to the page, you would want to either escape their value, so scripts could not run, or when you append it to the page, add it as a textNode which would cause the value to be text only and not possibly evaluated as code

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that this will be the answer :/ would it be reasonable to escape on the server side when I create the object before passing it to the Ajax response? I know that this harms the ‘escape as late as possible rule’. But that would be much easier because my JS code is so complex. Do you see any scenario where this is not sufficient?

Comment: You want to cleanse on the server side and the client side.  You should always cleanse on the server side to keep malicious content from becoming stored in your persisted data.  Cleansing/escaping on the client side is the fail safe just in case something got into your persisted storage that you failed to cleanse.

Comment: I already clean on the server side before storing it in the database. But once I retrieve it from the database and pass it to the Ajax response, I currently don’t escape or stanitize. Assuming I would do this, would it make escaping in JS obsolete?

Comment: It depends upon how comfortable you are with that level of escaping.  Those of a very strong security mindset would say the JS should still do it, just in case something on the backend is missed, or changes in the future and is no longer properly escaping.

Comment: I see... is there an easy way in JS to parse a multilevel object and escape malicious code? I guess I would rather escape the Ajax response once received on client side than to implement the escaping on every output